# Reshaping greyscale images for neural network training - how to do this correctly

Tags: image, opencv, neural-network, reshape

I have a general question about convolutional neural networks and image processing for training if your images are grey scale.

Take this image for example:

[image]

Its a grey scale image but when I do

```
image = cv2.imread("image.jpg")
print(image.shape)
```

I get

```
(1024, 1024, 3)
```

I know that opencv automatically creates 3 channels for jpg images. But when it comes to network training, it would be much more computationally efficient if I could use images in (1024, 1024, 1) - just like many of the MNIST tutorials demonstrate. However, if I reshape this:

```
image.reshape(1024, 1024 , 1)
```

And then try for example to show the image

```
plt.axis("off")
plt.imshow(reshaped_image)
plt.show()
```

I get

```
raise TypeError("Invalid dimensions for image data")
```

Does that mean that reshaping my images this way before network training is incorrect? I want to keep as much information in the image as possible but I don't want to have those extra channels if they aren't needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that you're getting the error is that the output of your `reshape` does not have the same number of elements as the input. From the documentation for [reshape](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#abca74fa43163dba52b70af4b48c69f62):

> - No extra elements are included into the new matrix and no elements are excluded. Consequently, the product rows*cols*channels() must stay the same after the transformation.

Instead, use [cvtColor](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga397ae87e1288a81d2363b61574eb8cab) to convert your 3-channel BGR image to a 1-channel grayscale image:

In Python:

```
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Or in C++:

```
cv::cvtColor(image, image, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
```

You could also avoid conversion altogether by reading the image using the `IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` flag:

```
image = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
or
image = cv2.imread(image_path, 0)
```

(Thanks to [@Alexander Reynolds](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5087436/alexander-reynolds) for the Python code.)

Comment: And just for completion here, in Python this would be `cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`. Additionally OP could just read the image as grayscale with `cv2.imread(image_path, 0)`.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds Yes, you're right. I totally overlooked that the OP was using Python in code snippets. I've updated the answer. Please feel free to edit if I've messed anything up. Thanks!

Comment: One other thing to be aware of. In Python, images are stored as numpy arrays and *not* as OpenCV `Mat`s. That means that none of the `Mat` methods are exposed to Python, so `img.reshape()` is *not* a `cv::Mat` method, but a numpy array method. The error is still for the same reason you mentioned and the method does the same thing, but the documentation linked is not related.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
for image_path in dir:
        img = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        X.append(img)
    X = np.array(X)
    X = np.expand_dims(X, axis=3)
```

set axis = Int : based on your array, 1 means it will prepend a new dimension in front.